Flutter app working on emulator but not working when I publish it and download it
Debug vs Release
I created a flutter app and tested it on ios and android emulator and it's working perfectly fine but when I published it to Google play store the ui is totally different and not working  why is that?
I tried flutter pub clean, it didn't work, I removed the unused dependencies  and finally I manually added the apk file on my phone (I thought the problem was witb the aab)

please add screen shot as well as add more info in your question to get answer

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

the issue was caused by get package in the dimensions file I was using
screenHeight = get.height; screenWidth = get.width;
I changed it to material package
I added this to the dimention package
static void init(BuildContext context) {
screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

}
and this in the main
@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Dimensions.init(context);

I hade one dependency that wasn't compatible with android
debug vs release
now the app now works only on Samsung series A but on the other it doesn't work or only opens once and then I get the same problem

The answer is unclear and lacks detail. Please specify the dependency causing the issue and provide more context or steps to resolve the problem.

The problem is not resolved I'm still facing this issue but now it only works on samsung a series
